# Getting Gridview Row By Datakeynames

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and it has `datakeynames="Id"`

I have that Id in code file. Now I want to get the row of a specific Id.

For example Id=1 then I want to get the row of gridview that has Id=1
I've used this code:

```
foreach (DataKey key in gdvMainList.DataKeys)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(key.Value) == consentReleaseId)
                    {
                        gdvMainListRow = gdvMainList.Rows[index];
                        break;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
```

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be loop through the items in the GridView until you find the matching key.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    if (GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["ID"] == consentReleaseId)
    {
        gdvMainListRow = row;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to bind the row ID into an element in the gridview row. Most often this occurs on an action link or button on the CommandArgument property.

```
<asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible="True" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
```

something like that. Then you can access the item and get the Row ID without any looping.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should be careful with your apporach is, if you have paging in your gridview, and if you are in a different page, you might end up pulling out wrong row or the row might not be found.

Instead of looping you can use a linq query on your datasource like

if your datasource is a list, 
obj = lObjs.Where( i => i.Id == consentReleaseId).First();

If you want to change something in the grid, you can change it in the obj and change the datasource.